# incorrect data returned from NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest

I am doing a NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest.  I give it the correct path to the new content but it always download older content.

aka I have two paths:
path1
path2

I create a requestString from path1.

Then I create the request:

```
NSURLRequest *requestDownload = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURLString]];
```

after that I do:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:requestDownload queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *downloadResponse, NSData *downloadData, NSError *dError) {
                     if(error)
                     {
                         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                         [self stopIndicator];
                     }
                     else{
                         NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", pdfPath);

                         if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pdfPath]) {
                                 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:pdfPath error:NULL];
                         }

                         [downloadData writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];
                         // Set the file modification date to the timestamp from the server
```

}

I breakpoint and look at the downloadResponse's URL and it is the accurate URL from 'path1', I check the server where the file is being downloaded from and the file is accurate there. But once the file is written to the Documents folder in the simulator, the file is from the 'path2' not from 'path1' where the async request was supposed to get its downloadData from...

TOTALLY confused here.  Funny thing it was working an hour ago then this behavior started cropping up.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you try deleting the file from the Documents folder? You are not checking that `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:pdfPath error:NULL];` doesn't return any error, so maybe it is just not deleting the previous file. And since you are not checking the new file has been written, you've no way to know something wrong happened.

Comment: thanks Bgi for the response.  I will add a check for error but I am looking at the file system while this occurs and do indeed see the file disappear.  Then the downloadData get written when I do the writeToFile, after I step the debugger.